# Motor Effect Experiment

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity

I recently saw an demonstration (image below) where the motor effect was being shown. They used the fact that forces come in pairs (Newton's third law) and so when current goes through the copper rod, a magnetic force is experienced by the rod, and an opposite and equal force is experienced by the metal channel (and magnets) on the electric balance. My question is, how does the balance keep showing a reading for more than a few seconds? Doesn't the motor effect only last a few seconds? (Also, the supply is dc)
[image]

Comment: It's not just a metal channel.  There's also a permanent magnet in the channel.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a current flowing through the metal rod there is a magnetic field surrounding it. This field interacts with the permanent magnetic field situated in the channel (look closely and you'll see one of the ferrite magnets - there's another opposite this one).
These two magnetic fields will attract or repel one another. The force is equal in magnitude but in opposite directions, e.g., the conductor may feel a force in the up direction whilst the magnets in the channel feel a force in the down direction (this is Newton's 3rd Law).
Using dc produces a constant magnetic field whilst the current flows; ac would produce an alternating field that varies too quickly to be observed/measured.

Comment: Welcome to the community and thank you for your reply! I just had a question, why does the reading continue to be shown? Doesn't the motor effect need a continuous change in the current direction or magnetic field direction to continue to show a reading on the scale (which is below the metal channel)?